# JQuery loaded in View not available in partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have the following View:

```
@model EDR.Presentation.WebMain.ViewModels.MvcSupportQueryViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Support Queries";
}

<div id="updatedContent">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_QueryList", Model); }
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Model Scripts/Support Queries/SupportQueries.js")
}
```

Here is the _QueryList Partial View:

```
@model EDR.Presentation.WebMain.ViewModels.MvcSupportQueryViewModel 

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<h2>Support Queries</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchQueries", "SupportQueries", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QueryFilter)
        @Html.DropDownList("QueryFilter", Model.QueryFilter)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DRTBUnitCollection)
        @Html.DropDownList("DRTBUnit", Model.DRTBUnitCollection)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />
}

<div class="lineSeperator-100"></div>

@if (Model.QueryCollection.ModelCollection.Items.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="table table-responsive">
        <table class="table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-1">Reference</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1">Type</th>
                    <th class="col-md-3">Facility</th>
                    <th class="col-md-4">Subject</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1">Date</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1">Resolved</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var value in Model.QueryCollection.ModelCollection.Items)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-1">@value.ReferenceNoDisplay</td>
                        <td class="col-md-1">@value.QueryType.DisplayName</td>
                        <td class="col-md-3">@value.Facility.Name</td>
                        <td class="col-md-4">@value.Subject</td>
                        <td class="col-md-1">@value.QueryDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td class="col-md-1">@value.IsResolved</td>
                        <td class="col-md-1">@Ajax.ActionLink("View", "ViewSupportQuery", new { queryID = value.ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent" },new { @class = "btn btn-info" })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    if (Model.QueryCollection.CanGoPrevious)
    { 
        @Ajax.ActionLink("<<", "Paging", new { pageNumber = Model.QueryCollection.PageNumber - 1, queryFilter = Model.UserQueryFilter.ToString(), drTBUnit = Model.FacilityID }, 
                                new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, 
                                new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
    }
    if (Model.QueryCollection.CanGoNext)
    {
        @Ajax.ActionLink(">>", "Paging", new { pageNumber = Model.QueryCollection.PageNumber + 1, queryFilter = Model.UserQueryFilter.ToString(), drTBUnit = Model.FacilityID },
                                new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "updatedContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace },
                                new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
    }

}
else
{
    @Html.Label("No Queries to display")
}
```

When I click on the View button within this Partial View, it returns another partial view, replacing all contents within the div element with the ID 'updatedContent'.

Here is the controller Action to support the "View" functionality.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult ViewSupportQuery(Guid queryID)
{
    var vm = new MvcSupportQueryViewModel()
    {
        QueryID = queryID
    };
    vm.GetQueryByID();

    return PartialView("_ViewQuery", vm);
}
```

However, after I clicked the "View" button, it opens up a new partial view. If I check my sources in Chrome, I can see that the JQuery file is no longer loaded.

The JQuery file is placed within a @section in my view, and from my understanding, including the JQuery in view, it should be available in all preceding partial views.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sound like you just just doing a normal redirect. Have you included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in your view or layout?

Comment: @StephenMuecke
Are you referring to the one included in this bundle?
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", 
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));

Comment: Yes. Is that being loaded in the main view (can't see it in your code)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked my sources again, and I can see that it is loaded.  The above bundle is loaded in my BundleConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the trouble seems to have been with my JQuery code.

I replaced the following JQuery code:

```
$("#btnAddResponse").on("click", function () {
    $("#hiddenContent").slideToggle();
});
```

With the following event delegation approach:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnAddResponse", function () {
    $("#hiddenContent").slideToggle();
});
```